# my developed android app only launches on version 4.1

Tags: android

I am Somehow new to android development , and i want your help please , after i developed my app and when testing , i can launch it and run it fine on my physical Note 2 or any 4.1 android version , but not on emulator even for the same version .

Please see my log cat error log .

```
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Frdaoud.moka/com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity.StartAnimations(SplashActivity.java:57)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:40)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     ... 11 more




    package com.Frdaoud.moka;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer OurSong;

    private long splashDelay = 3700; //3.7 seconds


    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        StartAnimations();
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo1);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);


        OurSong = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, R.raw.test1);
        OurSong.start();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);

            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Frdaoud.moka"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sermonsv"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sermons" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Service"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_service" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.LiveStreaming"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_live_streaming" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Services"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_services" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Atakal"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_atakal" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sad"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sad" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Heart"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_heart" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Pray"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pray" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Voicevideo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_voicevideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sermons2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sermons2" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Email"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_email" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Bible"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.HttpExample"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_http_example" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Side_navigation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_side_navigation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Moka"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_moka" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Slider"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_slider" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sermons3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sermons3" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Evan"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_evan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Timing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_timing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Fragment_1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Fragment_2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_2" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sermonsa"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sermonsa" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Prayers"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_prayers" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.ActionDrawerBasic"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_action_drawer_basic" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Apologetics"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apologetics" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Health"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_health" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Sexual"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sexual" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Quotes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_quotes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Frdaoud.moka.Quotesm"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_quotesm" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I used to have the same error before, the splash screen is taking too much memory that emulator cannot provide, you resize the splash pictures or make sure that the pics are supported to all drawable

Comment: What is at com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity.StartAnimations(SplashActivity.java:57) where it's NPE-ing?

Comment: edit your question and add AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Null Pointer Exception, that is why your app is getting crashed. Look at the logcat output carefully

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity.StartAnimations(SplashActivity.java:57)
11-10 09:19:18.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.Frdaoud.moka.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:40)
```

Check line 57 . Apply breakpoint and check whether it is getting any value or is it null. Use debugging tool. Post your Code too and mention which is line 57 in your code

Comment: i will do that and load it

Comment: I did Edit the question by adding the SpalahActivity which i think the problem from it . and i also add the manifest .

Comment: i tried changing the resolution of the splash screen but with  no effect

Comment: Which is line 57 in your code ? check on eclipse,.,You are getting a Null Pointer Exception dude. Some variable is becoming null

Comment: what i am not understanding that ,  if there is a problem , why it is not appearing when i am running my application on my Note 2 , 4.1  device ?? and only appearing on others ?

Comment: i am putting a small animation , picture going up on the main splash background , and also small sound wma file , 80 k  working with the spalsh screen ,  this is in my 57 line and when i remove all it works for the screen but not going after that to the main activity ..